# Return value based on matrix parameters

Tags: java, android

I am looking to implement an Android app that calculates the heat Index based on two parameters, temperature and humidity. I can extract the two variables from a **JSON** and compare them with the following table:

---

[image: Heat Index Table]
<sub>(source: [eurometeo.com](http://www.eurometeo.com/img/humidex.gif))</sub>

---

I am thinking of storing this table as a Matrix, bun I have no idea how to compare the data and return the appropriate value.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Regards,
Titus

Comment: Please ask a specific question.

Comment: There are several options for a data structure for the data in your table. I suggest that’ll be one of the first things to consider. Do you need to render the background colours from the table too?

Answer (score 0):

Here’s an option:

```
public class HeatIndexTable {

    // TODO write unittests for all methods in this class

    public static int minHumidity = 25;
    public static int maxHumidity = 100;
    public static int humidityStep = 5;

    public static int minTemperature = 22;
    public static int maxTemperature = 42;

    /** converts a humidity percentage to an index in our array */
    int humidityToIndex(int humidity) {
        if (humidity < minHumidity || humidity > maxHumidity || humidity % humidityStep != 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot handle humidity " + humidity);
        }
        return (humidity - minHumidity) / humidityStep;
    }

    /** converts a temperature in degrees to an index in our array */
    int temperatureToIndex(int temperature) {
        if (temperature < minTemperature || temperature > maxTemperature) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot handle temperature " + temperature);
        }
        return temperature - minTemperature;
    }

    int[][] heatIndex = new int[][] {
            { 22, 22, 22, 22, 23, /* etc. */ 31 },
            { 23, 23 /* etc. */ }
            // TODO fill in the rest
    };

    public int getHeatIndex(int temperature, int humidity) {
        return heatIndex[temperatureToIndex(temperature)][humidityToIndex(humidity)];
    }

}
```

With this you can go:

```
System.out.println(new HeatIndexTable().getHeatIndex(22, 45)); // prints 23
```

Hope it helps.